# Speed of convergence of an iterative method

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

**Problem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an analytical function with a simple root $\alpha$. Given an iteration
$$x_{r + 1} = x_r - \frac{f(x_r)^2}{f(x_r + f(x_r)) - f(x_r)},$$
prove that the order of convergence of a sequence $(x_n)_{n = 0} ^{\infty}$ is at least quadratic for $x_0$ sufficiently close to $\alpha$.

I've written $f$ in Taylor series around $\alpha$, since there's almost nothing else to do,
but the convergence comes out linear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Treat the problem as a functional iteration of the form $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$. Compute the the first few derivatives of $g$ and evaluate them at a zero $z$ of $f$. Do Taylor expansion of $g$ at $z$. Hopefully, you will find $x_{n+1} - z = g(x_n) - g(z) = c (x_n - z)^2 + O(x_n-z)^3$ for a suitable constant $c$.

Comment: @CarlChristian Can you elaborate a bit further? $g$ is undefined at $z$.

Comment: Can the situation be salvaged using l'Hospital's rule $f'$?